# Why do we need to specify the type template parameter for each class function defintion?

Tags: c++, templates, header

Since we define the template type over the class declaration, why do we have to specify it after each function definition? I'm confused because its even in the same file so it seems almost unnecessary to have to specify it over every function and because we are using the `::` operator shouldnt it go back to the class declaration and see that `T` is already defined.

I'm new to c++ and still need to clear up some misunderstandings.

```
#ifndef __Foo_H__
#define __Foo_H__

template <class T>
class Foobar{

  private:
    bool foo1(T);
    bool foo2(T);

  public:
   FooBar();

};

template <class T> bool FooBar<T>::foo1(T data){
 code..
}

template <class T> bool FooBar<T>::foo2(T data){
 code..
}

#endif
```

Comment: For starters, how else would the symbol `T` obtain its meaning?

Comment: well its already defined in over the class part.

Comment: i figured when we use the `::` operator it goes back to the class declaration and sees we already defined `T`

Comment: You could just as well write `template <class U> bool FooBar<U>::foo1(data)`. Member functions of class templates are themselves function templates.

Comment: Your code isn't actually correct. It has to be `template <class T> bool FooBar<T>::foo1(T data)` (note the `<T>`).

Comment: I see, I guess the relationship between the declaration and definitions are not as close as I thought.

Comment: Yeah, sort of. The template parameter names are not part of the template, if you will.

Comment: FWIW, there's either a proposal or was some discussion on getting rid of the template parameter repetition.

Answer (score 0):

First you may rename the argument as for normal function:

```
template <class U> bool FooBar<U>::foo1(U and_here_too){/**/}
```

It also manages to handle (partial) specialization:

```
template <> bool FooBar<int>::foo1(int i){/**/}
template <typename T> bool FooBar<std::vector<T>>::foo1(std::vector<T> v){/**/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates are example of generic programming. The idea is to reuse code/algorithms. In languages with strict type control you come across seemingly unnecessary constraints. For instance you may have some sorting function doing great job in one project but incompatible with types used in another.

C++, C#, and Java introduce generic programming as templates (C++) and generics (C#, Java). In generics (let's talk about Java) classes are existing entities and class parameters serve mainly as type control service. That is their purpose in collections. When you inspect how list works you see list gathers Objects and cast back to the parameterized type only when the object is retrieved. When you write class you can only assume the parameterized type is Object or declared interface like in the following example:

`class Test<T extends Comparable> {}`

Here you can use T as Comparable. Unless you explicitly declare the interface, the parameter is treated as Object.

Now comes the difference between generics and templates. In C++ you can assume much more about the parameterized type in implementation. You can write sorting of objects of unknown type. In Java you have to at least know what is interface the parameter type. This causes that C++ have to build new class for each parameter (in order to check if the code is correct). `Vector<int>` **is completely separate type from **`Vector<float>`. While in Java there exists one class `Vector<? extends Comparable>`.

`::` is scope operator. You can access scope of `Vector<int>` because the class exists, however, `Vector` does not.

As a result Java can compile generics and C++ cannot. All templates have to be available in headers to all programmers; you cannot hide it (there is some work to compile templates but I don't know what is its status).

So when you use generics you can refer to method `Vector.add()` while when templates you have to specify parameter `template<class T> Vector<T>`.

PS. since template parameter is integral part of class name you may use templates for compile time calculations like fibonaci sequence

```
template<int N> struct Fibonaci {
  static const int element = Fibonacci<N-1>::data + Fibonacci<N-2::data>;
}
template<1> struct Fibonaci {
  static const int element = 1;
}
template<0> struct Fibonaci {
  static const int element = 0;
}
```